# beforeShowMonth is not working in bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have used bootstrap datepicker in my project which is then tied to the html is as follows

```
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

I works fine till here but when I tried to capture event called `beforeShowMonth` its not working, I mean I have put one console.log statement into it but its not getting printed, because command is not reaching there. Same way if I try `beforeShowDay` it works fine. what can be the error, or am I making any non sense mistake while capturing the event.
angularjs controller code is as follows

```
$('#calendar').datepicker({
            format:"yyyy-mm-dd",
            setDate: new Date(),
            todayHighlight: true,
            beforeShowMonth: function(date){
                console.log("In before Show month: "+date.getMonth());
            },
            beforeShowDay: function(date){
                console.log("In before Show Day");
            }
        });
```

Any suggestion?
If not then can anyone tell me how can I write `beforeShowDay` after initializing. I have used `option` to do it this also not working. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

The beforeShowMonth and beforeShowDay MUST return some of those options:

- undefined to have no effect
- A Boolean, indicating whether or not this date is selectable
- A String representing additional CSS classes to apply to the date’s cell
- An object with the following properties

```html
beforeShowMonth: function(date){
 console.log("In before Show month: "+date.getMonth());3
 return "";
},
beforeShowDay: function(date){
 console.log("In before Show Day");
 return "";
}
```